# Reduce for a difficult case

Tags: equation-solving

I have to see the x for this case how should be?!

```
    Reduce[{( Sqrt[ f + a^2/(4 b^2)]/ f Log[12 x b^2 f + 3 x a^2 + Sqrt[3]
      x Sqrt[(4 b^2 f + a^2) (4 b (((2 - 3 b) k)/x^2 + 3 b f) + 
        3 a^2)]] - a/(2 b f)ArcTanh[(x a)/Sqrt[4/3 (2 - 3 b) b k + x^2 (4 b^2 f + a^2)]] - a/(4 b f) Log[(-2 + 3 b) k - 3 x^2 b f]) > 0, f > 0, b > 0, a > 0}, x, Reals]
```

thank you

Comment: After all this time and +7 upvotes on the answer, you probably shouldn't change the question. Just chalk it up to a mistake and ask a new one. See https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/handling-questions-and-associated-answers-when-question-is-fundamentally-changed

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my bad.

Comment: That's ok. You can roll back the edit, or I can do it.

Answer (score 8):

Let's first check the conditions on the parameters by including the function domain restrictions (implied by specifying `Reals`) but omitting at first the main inequality.  We'll simplify this bit and come back to the main question.  There are three complicated, transcendental functions in the main term, two involving `Log` and one involving `ArcTanh`. We'll add their function domains to the restrictions. These are already implied, but we're helping `Reduce` out by singling them out:

```
Reduce[{
  (*(Sqrt[f+a^2/(4 b^2)]/f Log[12 x b^2 f+3 x a^2+Sqrt[
  3] x Sqrt[(4 b^2 f+a^2) (4 b (((2-3 b) k)/x^2+3 b f)+3 a^2)]]-
  a/(2 b f)ArcTanh[(x a)/Sqrt[4/3 (2-3 b) b k+x^2 (4 b^2 f+a^2)]]-
  a/(4 b f) Log[(-2+3 b) k-3 x^2 b f])>0,*)
  f > 0, b > 0, a > 0, 
  FunctionDomain[
   Log[12 x b^2 f + 3 x a^2 + 
     Sqrt[
       3] x Sqrt[(4 b^2 f + a^2) (4 b (((2 - 3 b) k)/x^2 + 3 b f) + 
          3 a^2)]], x],
  FunctionDomain[
   ArcTanh[(x a)/Sqrt[4/3 (2 - 3 b) b k + x^2 (4 b^2 f + a^2)]], x],
  FunctionDomain[Log[(-2 + 3 b) k - 3 x^2 b f], x]},
 x, Reals]

(*  False  *)
```

The result `False` means there are no real `x` satisfying the constraints.  Adding the main inequality could only restrict the answer more, but of course, starting from "no solutions," the only possible result is still "no solutions."

Comment: Therefore, under which condition this equation will be positive?

Comment: @ArminSharafi I doubt it can be solved, the system being transcendental, but to find out, you should solve for the parameters, not for `x`.

Comment: @ArminSharafi When I try solving for `{a, b, k, f}`, it still says no real solutions (`False`). Unless you want to relax the constraints....

Comment: I was thinking maybe ContourPlot will be useful?!!

Comment: I just realized that the equation it was not correct, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

```
   g[x_] := (Sqrt[4 a b^2 + f^2]
 ArcCoth[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 a b^2 + f^2] x)/Sqrt[4 b (-2 + 3 b) k + 3 (4 a b^2 + f^2) x^2]] - f Log[(3 f + b Sqrt[36 a + (3 (3 f^2 + (4 b (-2 + 3 b) k)/x^2))/b^2]) x])/(2 a b);
```

a = 0.7; f = 0.2; b = 1;
Plot[g[x] /. {k -> -0.04}, {x, 0.01, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]

[image]